# <sup> Superscript tag not working as expected

Tags: html, superscript

I have a superscript tag in my  however that  tag is not working as expected, it doesn't display in top or little upper side of the subtext

```
<td name="name">
<span class="container">
<a name="description">Protection</a>
</span>
<sup style="font-size:.6em">1</sup> 
<div name="limit" class="ismedium">
$12345
</div>
</td>
```

[image]

If i remove style property from  tag then the text 1 doesn't have any superscript effect it just displays as normal text as below

```
<td name="name">
    <span class="container">
    <a name="description">Protection</a>
    </span>
    <sup>1</sup> 
    <div name="limit" class="ismedium">
    $12345
    </div>
    </td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please find the code below:

```html
<td name="name">
    <span class="container">
      <a name="description">Protection</a>
      <sup>1</sup> 
    </span>
    <div name="limit" class="ismedium">$12345</div>
</td>
```